# Ejecutar método en segundo plano

Tags: asp.net, backgroundworker

Buen día sucede que tengo un gridview en asp .net, el cual se debe enviar por correo a ciertos usuarios cada lunes y jueves. Se debe enviar sin que el usuario se haya loguedo y sin que haya iniciado sesión en la aplicación, y **quisiera saber si es eso posible.**
Estuve leyendo sobre **[hangfire](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-web-app.html)**  para hacerlo en segundo plano, el problema es que según entendí, solo se puede hacer si la aplicación esta activa, y yo necesito que se envié ese correo si el usuario esta durmiendo o de vacaciones, etc, sin necesidad de entrar al sitio.
Gracias.
Este es mi código para enviar el gridview por correo:
Lo puse dentro de un button1_click pero esa no es la idea

```html
protected void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (SendHTMLMail())
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('Correo enviado correctamente');</script>");
}
else
{
Response.Write("<script>alert('Error al enviar correo');</script>");
}
}
public bool SendHTMLMail()
{
loadGrid();
con.Open();
try
{
string sql = "SELECT correo FROM FUsuarios WHERE Nombre = '" + Session["Nombre"] + "'";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
string correo = Convert.ToString(cm.ExecuteScalar());
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("webmail@gmail.com");
// Sender e-mail address.
Msg.From = fromMail;
// Recipient e-mail address.
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(correo));
// Subject of e-mail
Msg.Subject = "Seguimiento a Produccion";              
Msg.Body += " " + GetGridviewData(GridView1);               
Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
string sSmtpServer = "";
sSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
a.Host = sSmtpServer;
a.Port = 587;
a.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
("webmail@gmail.com", "contraseña");
a.EnableSsl = true;
a.Send(Msg);
con.Close();
return true;
}
catch (Exception er)
{
Label1.Text = er.ToString();
return false;
}
}
public string GetGridviewData(GridView gv)
{
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter strWriter = new StringWriter(strBuilder);
HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(strWriter);
try
{
gv.RenderControl(htw);
}
catch (Exception er)
{
er.ToString();
}
return strBuilder.ToString();
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
/* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET server control at run time. */
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco hangfire tambien se puede configurar con una base de datos para que se disparen las tareas a la hora y dia programada. Claro, que como tu logica de enviar correo esta en tu aplicacion entonces debe estar arriba para que se ejecute.

Comment: Suena a que esto lo deberia hacer un servicio por fuera de tu aplicación. O alguien debe entrar a mano y "ejecutar" algun proceso de envios

Comment: Una solucion rapida es que te crees un servicio ASMX o WebApi y coloques tu logica de enviar correo en el servicio. Despues, desde tu base de datos te creas o configuras un JOB que se dispare todos los lunes y jueves y dentro del JOB colocas que llame al servicio web que creaste anteriormente.

Comment: gracias por su respuesta @OrlandoDeLaRosa pero a que se refiere con "debe estar arriba para que se ejecute"?

Comment: "debe estar arriba para que se ejecute" = que la aplicacion este activa.